# Assign show function functionality to another keyword

Tags: haskell

```
data Sentence = S String

instance Show Sentence where
         show (S p) = p
```

For input

```
show (S "y")
```

Output is

```
"y"
```

What should I add to my code that I get the same result but instead of using keyword "show" I use "print?

```
print (S "y")
"y"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` is not a keyword. It's an identifier. It identifies a function.

In order to use `print` instead of it, just tell the compiler that you want the identifier `print` to identify the same function as `show`:

```
print = show
```

If you want to add a type signature to it (you don't have to, but it's a good practice), that signature will have to include the `Show` constraint, because that's whence the function `show` comes:

```
print :: Show a => a -> String
print = show
```

Alternatively, if you wanted the function `print` to only apply to type `Sentence` (rather than any showable type), you can make your type signature specify that:

```
print :: Sentence -> String
print = show
```

In this case the `Show` constraint isn't necessary, because the compiler knows the type and can lookup the `Show` instance for it.

Comment: I would add a warning against repurposing the name "print", which is a built-in IO action for printing a "showable" value to standard output. Since that's available in Prelude any custom function called print will lead to ambiguity (and I think compiler errors, although I'm not 100% sure on that).